# MPAndroidChart, how to get the first and last visible x-index after a zoom?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

When a user does zoom on a line chart, I need to make some calculations only on visible values.
In older versions of MPAndroidChart there were 2 functions called `getLowestVisibleXIndex()` & `getLowestVisibleXIndex()`. 
These functions are not available in version >= 3.0.3. 
How can I find these values?

Answer (score 0):

These are the new methods to do the same in newer versions:

```
chart.getHighestVisibleX()

chart.getLowestVisibleX()
```

They are defined here:
[HorizontalBarChart.java](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/c1f6fcebf0c3516e067b34312b283189f909bde5/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/HorizontalBarChart.java)